# Erlang: Extracting values from a Key/Value tuple

Tags: get, erlang, key, tuples

I have a tuple list that look like this:

```
{[{<<"id">>,1},
  {<<"alerts_count">>,0},
  {<<"username">>,<<"santiagopoli">>},
  {<<"facebook_name">>,<<"Santiago Ignacio Poli">>},
  {<<"lives">>,{[{<<"quantity">>,8},
                 {<<"max">>,8},
                 {<<"unlimited">>,true}]}}]}
```

I want to know how to extract properties from that tuple. For example:

```
get_value("id",TupleList), %% should return 1.

get_value("facebook_name",TupleList), %% should return "Santiago Ignacio Poli".

get_value("lives"), %% should return another TupleList, so i can call      

get_value("quantity",get_value("lives",TupleList)).
```

I tried to match all the "properties" to a record called "User" but I don't know how to do it.

To be more specific: I used the Jiffy library (github.com/davisp/jiffy) to parse a JSON. Now i want to obtain a value from that JSON.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first strange thing is that the tuple contains a single item list: where `[{Key, Value}]` is embedded in `{}` for no reason. So let's reference all that stuff you wrote as a variable called `Stuff`, and pull it out:

```
{KVList} = Stuff
```

Good start. Now we are dealing with a `{Key, Value}` type list. With that done, we can now do:

```
lists:keyfind(<<"id">>, 1, KVList)
```

or alternately:

```
proplists:get_value(<<"id">>, KVList)
```

...and we would get the first answer you asked about. (Note the difference in what the two might return if the Key isn't in the KVList before you copypasta some code from here...).

A further examination of this particular style of question gets into two distinctly different areas:

- Erlang docs regarding data functions that have `{Key, Value}` functions (hint: the `lists`, `proplists`, `orddict`, and any other modules based on the same concept is a good candidate for research, all in the standard library), including basic filter and map.
- The underlying concept of data structures as semantically meaningful constructs. Honestly, I don't see a lot of deliberate thought given to this in the functional programming world outside advanced type systems (like in Haskell, or what Dialyzer tries hard to give you). The best place to learn about this is relational database concepts -- once you know what "5NF" *really* means, then come back to the real world and you'll have a different, more insightful perspective, and problems like this won't just be trivial, they will beg for better foundations.

Comment: It worked, thank you!
Is a good practice to call one function per property? (for example if i need to fetch the username, the id, and the Facebook name). It's not like a getter which is a O(1) operation, so i'm worried about the performance in a real-time scenario.

Comment: I come from an 6-year or so Java experience, so i'm still get used to funcional programming, but is great!

Comment: @SantiagoIgnacioPoli Yes, calling a function per property is the Java equivalent of calling a getter per property. `lookup(id, Proplist)` is directly equivalent to `proplist.get_id()`. In this case we would say "a call per element" or "a call per lookup" since that it *actually* what is going on, in either language.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [proplists module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) and their [`proplist:get_value/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_value-2) function.

You just need to think how it should behave when `Key` is not present in the list (or is the default proplists behavior satisfying).

And two notes:

- since you keys are binnary, you should use `<<"id">>` in your function
- proplists works on lists, but data you presented is list inside one element tuple. So you need to extract this you `Data`.

  `{PropList} = Data,
  Id = proplists:get_value(<<"id">>, PropList),`

Comment: I tried to use this approach but i get this error:

{"init terminating in do_boot",{function_clause,[{proplists,get_value,["id",{[{<<2 bytes>>,119},{<<12 bytes>>,0},{<<8 bytes>>,<<12 bytes>>},{<<11 bytes>>,<<10 bytes>>},{<<13 bytes>>,<<21 bytes>>},{<<15 bytes>>,true},{<<12 bytes>>,true},,undefined],[{file,"proplists.erl"},{line,225}]},{test,test,0,

Comment: To be more specific: I used the Jiffy library (https://github.com/davisp/jiffy) to parse a JSON. Now i want to obtain a value from that JSON.